# PHP - unlink won't delete files

Tags: php, file, directory, delete-file, unlink

Essentially, the following code works fine except for the 'unlink' sections. The record is located and deleted in the database, but the file in the server directory remains untouched.

I know that 'pageLocation' is accurate because I've used it to load files.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmitEdit'])) 
{
    $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png');
    $max_filesize = 10485760;
    $setComic = $_SESSION['comicID'];
    $setPage = $_SESSION['currentPage'];
    $upload_path = 'comics/'.$setComic.'/';

    $filename = $_FILES['fileToEdit']['name'];
    $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
    die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

    if(filesize($_FILES['fileToEdit']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
    die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

    if(!is_writable($upload_path))
    die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

    include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');

    $query1 = ("SELECT pageLocation FROM page WHERE pageID = '$setPage'");
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
    {
        unlink('/"'.$row['pageLocation'].'"');
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToEdit']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)) 
    {
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE page SET pageLocation='".$upload_path . $filename."' WHERE pageID=".$setPage.""); 
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }

    else 
    {
        echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';
    }
    header('Location: uploadPage.php');
}
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmitDelete']))
{
    $setPage = $_SESSION['currentPage'];
    include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');

    $query2 = ("SELECT pageLocation FROM page WHERE pageID = '$setPage'");
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc())
    {
        unlink('/"'.$row['pageLocation'].'"');
        mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM page WHERE pageID = '$setPage'");
    }
    header('Location: uploadPage.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: To clarify, edit removes the previous image and replaces it with another while delete just removes it.

Comment: Have you checked the permission?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but how would I go about doing that?

Comment: What does `$row['pageLocation']` print out? Give us an example.

Comment: you can use php function `fileperms($file)`

Comment: `'/"'` you really need quotes inside these paths?

Comment: $row['pageLocation'] would print out the filepath and filename of the image matching the pageID, for example 'comics/0/000.jpg'

Comment: @Ghost I think OP's trying to use `/` to go to the root, and "comics" is a sub-folder from the root. There's indeed a quotes issue. However, if OP's wanting to go to the root, using `/` won't work unless using a full system path; what do you think? OP should use a relative path or just omit it if running script "from" the root.

Comment: @Ghost The quotes were something to do with using variables in place of a string. e.g. "'.$row['pageLocation'].'"

Comment: @alex494 Try `unlink("'.$row['pageLocation'].'");` - the `/` you used, I think you're trying to access the root, correct?

Comment: Turns out it was the quotes after all. I was under the impression you needed single quotes (' ') for the filepath, but apparently the variable alone is enough.

Comment: Yes I was accessing root (it's a WAMP server so I run the scripts from the 'www' folder with the 'comics' folder on the same level as the scripts.

Comment: Another happy ending ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes those `quotes` there doesn't make sense, it shouldn't be there in the first place. just straight up feed the path

Comment: Incidentally, `CHMOD it to 777` is a very bad idea. You also have at least one SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks all, question closed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- wins again! :D

Comment: @Darren hahaha! Well, I did have some help from Ghost ;) I was merely assisting. Ghost spotted the quotes issue.